# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

Tags: java, class, jsp

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
```

> An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file:
>   [D:\BT.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\EP-SERVICEPLUS\org\apache\jsp\WEB_002dINF\views\customjsp_16_2020\SendEmail_jsp.java]
>   Only a type can be imported.
>   com.org.ep.srvpls.entity.ActionOnTaskDataForCustormJsp resolves to a
>   package
>   Stacktrace:
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:485)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:379)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
>       at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:604)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:543)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
>       at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.approval.ActionNew_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f78(ActionNew_jsp.java:14053)
>       at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.approval.ActionNew_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fotherwise_005f12(ActionNew_jsp.java:13976)
>       at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.approval.ActionNew_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fchoose_005f0(ActionNew_jsp.java:3282)
>       at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.approval.ActionNew_jsp._jspService(ActionNew_jsp.java:1961)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at com.org.ep.filter.AnnotationFilter.doFilter(AnnotationFilter.java:152)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:67)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: That's the exception contents, but what is your question? I could say that we know what would be your question, but there is no information helpful in solving it.

Answer (score 0):

The error implies that you have a package named com.org.ep.srvpls.entity.ActionOnTaskDataForCustormJsp which you are trying to import in the JSP page. com.org.ep.srvpls.entity.ActionOnTaskDataForCustormJsp should be a java class. Can you double check that, if thats not the problem post the source of the JSP.